# R.java file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm doing my first projects with Android Studio and I've found that I get an error with the R.java file, because in every class when I make a reference to R.id.X it turns red and it says that it cannot resolve the symbol R..does anyone can help me with this?

[image]

Comment: try cleaning your code, check for any xml error...

Comment: Rebuilding usually solves this problem for me. Yes, also ensure you don't have any errors in your xml file.

Comment: you need to import R class to your code. try alt + enter for suggestion in android studio and look for imports it should be something like import your.package.name.R;

Comment: Post your code of your `imports`

Comment: Sometimes only Cleaning Projects works...

Answer (score 0):

It happens often with everyone when trying to import a project or opening previous projects....It's not a programming error and it can be fixed easily...**This always works for me...**

```
- Build->Clean Project
- Build-> Rebuild Projects
- File-> Invalidate Caches/ Restart
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several probability that make the error happens:

1. Error in xml code
   When we have a wrong open or close tag in XML or wrong attribute in a resource like **layout**, **strings.xml**, **AndroidManifest.xml**, etc, it will makes the error for R.java. So, you need to fix them to resolve the error.
2. Using invalid name in drawable
   Sometimes we face this error:

   > Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

   It means that we have an invalid name for drawable like `MyDrawable.png`. Change it to `mydrawable.png` or `my_drawable.png` or any string with character from a to z and 0 to 9 and a `_`.
3. Using the wrong package name for import in java code.
   This is usually happens when we refactoring the app package name but forget to change the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml`. For example, if we have a package name `com.example.project` we should have the same package name in AndroidManifest.xml. Something like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.project">
      ...
   </manifest>
   ```

   Then, we need to import the R.java `with import com.example.project.R;`
4. Using already removed custom view library.
   When we previously using a custom view and currently don't want to use it anymore, we usually delete the dependency from the build.gradle. But we accidentally forget to remove the custom view in our layout. So, check the view before removing the custom view dependency.

After resolving one of the problems above, we can clear and rebuild the project. If the problem still persist, then use the last resort. Use `File-> Invalidate Caches/ Restart...` from Android Studio menu.